# When was contemporary logical notation established

Tags: logic, notation, math-history

When contemporary fundamental logical notation was established? I mean basic symbols as used nowadays $\iff\implies\land\lor\lnot\forall\exists\vdash\models$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is different for different symbols. It wasn't invented all at once,  but accreted gradually.  Even closely-related symbols like $\land$ and $\lor$ or $\forall $ and $\exists $ were introduced separately. (Strange but true.)

$\lor $ dates to the 19th century and is an abbreviation for Latin *vel*. $\land$ didn't come until the following century by analogy with  $\lor $ and with $\cup $ and $\cap $.

$\exists $ was invented by G. Peano for his *Principles of Arithmetic* (1889), which was enormously influential, and also [probably the last major scientific work to be written in Latin](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/637/what-was-the-last-important-scientific-work-written-in-latin). It also introduced $\supset $ for implication, originally an upside-down capital ‘C’.  Gentzen introduced $\forall $  in 1935 by analogy with $\exists$ in [*Untersuchungen über das logische Schließen*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0039&DMDID=DMDLOG_0032&LOGID=LOG_0032&PHYSID=PHYS_0184) ("Investigations on Logical Reasoning").

$\vdash $ and $\lnot $ are abbreviations of the elaborate notation of [G. Frege's *Begriffsschrift*](https://archive.org/details/gottlob-frege-begriffsschrift-english/page/18/mode/2up).  $\vdash $ was introduced in *Principia Mathematica*. $\vDash $ came later, analogous to $\vdash $. $\sim $ for logical negation is much older than $\lnot $ and is an altered letter 'N', but Hilbert used it to mean logical equivalence instead of negation.   Gentzen attributes $\lnot$ to Heyting.

$\to $ for implication is ancient,  going back at least to Boole. I don't know when $\implies$ was introduced but it will be hard to trace since even today the distinction between $\to $ and $\implies $ is not standard.

If I were going to give a short summary,  it would be that it came together in the early part of the 20th century,  based on equal parts Peano, Frege, and older traditions,  modified by *Principia Mathematica*, and had settled down by 1930 or so.

The Van Heijenoort sourcebook would be a good place to start looking if you wanted to follow up in more detail.

Comment: You can check [here](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) for $\rightarrow$ : Hilbert (1922); Peano (1898) and W&R (1910) used : $\supset$. For $\Rightarrow$ : Bourbaki (1954). $\forall$ seems due to Gentzen (1935) and $\land$ to Heyting (1930), as well as $\lnot$; Peano and W&R used $\sim$. $\lor$ for disjunction is Russell (1908).

Comment: Will assumption that similar notation to ours was in common use around 1930 be correct?

Comment: According to S.C.Kleene, *Mathematical logic* (1967), page 36, the symbol $\vdash$, used already by Frege and W&R, was used with the meaning of "derivable" by Rosser (1935) and Kleene, [Proof by Cases in Formal Logic](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1968749?uid=2134&uid=3738296&uid=378508351&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3&uid=378508341&uid=60&sid=21104824857971) (1934), while the symbol $\vDash$ for the corresponding semantical relation was used by Kleene in his 1956 lectures : [Sets, logic and mathematical fouindations](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015017346720;view=1up;seq=1).

Comment: "It also introduced ⊃ for implication" Was this symbol meant to be related to subset?